# What is "Energy Lake"?

Tags: bios, power-management

My Phoenix AwardBIOS setup utility offers an enabled/disabled option for "Energy Lake function", with default being disabled.

In a year 2009 document *Intel® Desktop Boards BIOS Settings Dictionary* I find:

> Energy Lake technology introduces two main end-user features: the
>   “Consumer Electronics” (CE)-like device power behavior, and
>   maintaining system state and data integrity during power loss events).

However I still don't understand. What is the use of this function?

Answer (score 0):

Its an energy management technology, evidently is a very low power state and is a rare feature and not widely adopted.

Sounds like a server Motherboard since it preserves system state and data integrity during power failure. I have seen internal battery backup for raid cards that perform similar functions during power failure.

Other than what you and I have posted there is no further documentation.

[image]

[Source of Information](http://www.bios-info.de/4p92x846/befe.htm)